# mongo: efficiently retaining only the most recent N duplicate records

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Given:

- Several million records in a mongo collection.
- Each record has 10 fields, of which 4 make a compound non unique index, lets call them the KEY.
- Each record has a timestamp.
- Some records have the same KEY value.
- It is possible that the same KEY is found in thousands of records.

I would like to create another collection, containing a subset of the original collection, where I want to limit the number of duplicates per every KEY to no more than some constant, for instance 1000, where only the most recent duplicates must be included.

So, if there are 10000 records with the same KEY, then there will be only the 1000 most recent ones in the new collection.

Below is my code to create an aggregated collection, containing all the original records grouped by KEY. So, I missing the part of retaining only the most recent 1000, but my code is already extremely inefficient, so I've figured I am doing something wrong already:

```
from pymongo import Connection

def main():
  with Connection() as connection:
    mydb = connection.mydb
    try:
      mydb.aggregated.drop()
      mydb.static.map_reduce("""
// map
function() {
  emit({
    indexed_field1: this.indexed_field1,
    indexed_field2: this.indexed_field2,
    indexed_field3: this.indexed_field3
  }, {
    id: this._id,
    ts: this.ts,
    // other fields
  });
}
""", """
// reduce - group the records with the same KEY
// return the given values array wrapped in an object
function(key, values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    if (values[i].items) {
      values[i] = values[i].items;
    }
  }
  return {items: values};
}
""", 'aggregated', finalize="""
// finalize by flattening the value, which is likely to be an array of nested arrays
function(key, value) {
  function flatten(value, collector) {
    var items = value;
    if (!(value instanceof Array)) {
      if (!value.items) {
        collector.push(value);
        return;
      }

      items = value.items;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      flatten(items[i], collector);
    }
  }

  var collector = [];
  flatten(value, collector);
  return collector;
}
""")
    except Exception as exc:
      print exc

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Another problem is that I violate the principal that reduce should return the same type as map, but I think it is OK in my case, because my reduce and finalize deal with it.

It feels that I am on a wrong track. Advices?

**EDIT**

The data looks like this:

```
{_id: , key1: , key2: , key3: , ts: , bla-bla-bla}
```

For instance:

- 20,000 records with `(key1,key2,key3) == ('yaba', 'daba', 'doo')`
- 15,000 records with `(key1,key2,key3) == ('yogi', 'bear', '')`
- 700 records with `(key1,key2,key3) == ('yo', 'ho', 'ho')`
- and so on

At the end of the process I need to be left with:

- 1,000 most recent yaba-daba-doo records
- 1,000 most recent yogi-bear records
- all the yo-ho-ho records (because there are less than 1000 of them)
- and so on

Comment: It is paramount that your input and output of reduce be the same... it isn't enough to "think it is OK because my reduce and finalize deal with it".  You cannot guarantee how many times the reduce function may run to produce a final result and a lack of idempotence will lead to inconsistent behavior which it appears you may be encountering.

Comment: Why is it paramount if the only code that deals with it is mine, namely map, reduce and finalize? And if you observe the enclosed source code the reduce and finalize functions deal with it quite well - they expect several possible kinds of input. The enclosed code has been tested - it works correctly, only the whole approach is inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a bad feeling I am missing something really important here and should prolly sober up before I decide to try and program but:-

Ok so given you have a document that could potentially look like:

```
{
  _id: {},
  key1: '', key2: '', key3: '', key4: '', key5: '', key6: '', key7: '', key8: '', key9: '', key10: ''
}
```

You want to take, say, the compound key of [key2, key3, key5, key7] and then pull out the latest 1000 repeated documents with this exact key.

Can't this be solved with a little hacking? I mean you are essentially getting 1k of the latest of a key??

```
db.awesome_collection.find({ 'key2': '', 'key3': '', 'key5': '', 'key7': '' }).sort({ 'ts': -1 }).limit(1000);
```

Doesn't that do it?

I mean being really intelligent you can actually make a script that could run faster than an MR to go through the original table to buld anew one based upon these sort of queries.

Comment: I have edited my post. You should see now where you have misunderstood me.

Comment: Im still confused :S I mean you know the values you wanna back or is it that you don't know the values you want back and you are going through the collection with a set compound constraint getting all unique combinations of it? So you are distincting the table and then grabbing 1000 (or less if there ain't 1000) per unique entry? If so it might be good to implement a increnmental MR to distinct and then use the query above.

Comment: You could do this all in one MR but it would be inefficient and slow, even slower than what you have atm..I mean you could have a delta MR with maybe two quick queries client side, even store a cache table of the 1000 and make it all into a nice little cronjob (by delta MR I mean incremental)

Comment: I do not know the key values apriori. I know that there are duplicates, some key combinations may be duplicated a few times only and some - thousands of times. I need to reduce the number of duplicates per key while removing only the oldest records.

Comment: Yea in this case I would do a distinct MR and then use the results of that as a lookup table for the query I stated above.

As for making your MR work the only real way to house a global array of seen index combinations and count them as you go along really.